# Have to click image twice for function to work

Tags: jquery, html, function

This code works great, except for one thing and I cannot figure out why it is messing up. For the top image, or "#personalinsurance", I have to click it twice for the function to happen. This is only for the first time that you use the feature. If any of the other ID's are clicked, "#businessinsurance" or "#assetpreservation", the function works on the first click. This function just makes a div appear in the div "#insurpic" when one of the "insurtypes" images are clicked. So my question is, what can I do to make it work on the first click?

Also, is there something I can change to make the div show up with a little bit more...grace? It just appears, it would be great if it slid in or something cool like that! But in reality, I just need help with the first question, and if you help me out with this part then you're just that much cooler!

Link to Website where code is used [Website](http://www.greenwaysave.com/)

Below is the HTML and jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="insurtypes"> <a href='#personalinsurnace'>
    <img src="img/personal_insurance.png" />
    </a>  <a href='#businessinsurance'>
    <img src="img/business_insurance.png" />
    </a>
 <a href='#assetpereservation'>
    <img src="img/asset_preservation.png" />
    </a>

</div>
<div id="insurpic">
    <div id="personalinsurnace"><b>Personal Insurance Services</b>
        <br />choose the service you are interested in!
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="businessinsurance"><b>Business Insurance Services</b>
        <br />choose the service you are interested in!
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="assetpereservation"><b>Asset Preservation Services</b>
        <br />choose the service you are interested in!
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#insurtypes').each(function () {

    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {

        if ($(this).is('.active')) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
        } else {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: no problem running in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEJJ9/)

Comment: Seems like on load, everything is set to active, then clicking it hides it. What isn't working?

Comment: Is there more information that I need to provide? I know that it does not work correctly on the website. Could the problem be with css then? All of the 3 "insurtypes" have the same css minus colors used.

Comment: I just have to click 2 times for the function to work on the top image.

Comment: Adding Link to website where this code is used in the post.

Comment: @GlennV., Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `e.preventDefault()` right after the `click` event starts.

Add right after the click event:

```
$(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
```

Full Code:

```
$('#insurtypes').each(function () {

    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).is('.active')) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
        } else {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();
        }
    });
});
```

And make sure you remove the `e.preventDefault();` in the last line of the event function

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have to click on the top image twice for the function to work, even with the changes that you suggested to the code.